# Moveit import scene from text automatically

Tags: c++, rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic, planning-scene

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We can export and import Moveit scene objects to/from a text file (*.scene) using the RViz GUI (picture below). I would like to do the same automatically, so that the scene will be loaded on start. I am aware of the option of [creating collision objects by code](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html), however I want to have a more maintainable approach (data over code).

Is there a way to save/load Moveit planning scene objects to/from text, using C++ API or using an existing ros node/service?

System: Ubuntu 16.04, ROS-Kinetic

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287394/moveit-import-scene-from-text-automatically/) by [hansolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29473/hansolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2018-04-03

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a node under moveit_ros_planning_type pkg, where you can pass argument and publish scene.
Just add this to your launch file:

```
<arg name="scene_file" default="$(find project_name)/config/file.scene"/> 
<node name = "moveit_publish_scene_from_text" pkg= "moveit_ros_planning" type = "moveit_publish_scene_from_text" args= "$(arg scene_file)"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [skipPant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27386/skippant/) with karma: 68 on 2018-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6